# React Native build error on iOS simulator from VSCode

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with building my react native app .. this happens only on iOS and Android works fine.
So when i run:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

I get pretty long description but all of them are warnings except these two:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      _MLKLog in MLKitCommon(MLKLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDTCORTransport", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKFirelogTransport.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(GIPLoggingReroutingGTMLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(PHTInternalHeterodyneSyncer.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(PHTHeterodyneSyncer.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(GIPPseudonymousIDStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTLogOutputStream.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTClearcutUploader.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTClearcutMetaLogger.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTClearcutFileUtility.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionCookieStorage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTClearcutUploader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(CCTClearcutUploader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(PHTFlatFilePhenotype.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKModelDownloader.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitVision(GMVCloudVisionClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULCCComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKCustomModelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULCCComponentContainer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKContext.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKCustomModelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULCCComponentType", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKModelManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKContext.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKCustomModelManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULUserDefaults", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKModelPreferencesManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKAnalyticsLogger.o)
      objc-class-ref in MLKitCommon(MLKModelDownloader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBridge", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MLKITx_GIPLoggingReroutingGTMLogger in MLKitCommon(GIPLoggingReroutingGTMLogger.o)
  "_RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_RCTAppSetupPrepareApp", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
      ___91-[MLKITx_PHTInternalHeterodyneSyncer syncHoldingLockWithSyncedScopes:fetchReason:callback:]_block_invoke in MLKitCommon(PHTInternalHeterodyneSyncer.o)
      ___150-[MLKITx_PHTHeterodyneSyncer batchSyncWithAccounts:syncedScopes:fetchReason:throttlingCache:heterodyneSyncInfo:accountToAuthToken:lastError:callback:]_block_invoke in MLKitCommon(PHTHeterodyneSyncer.o)
      ___69-[MLKModelDownloader beginModelDownloadWithURL:modelInfo:conditions:]_block_invoke.285 in MLKitCommon(MLKModelDownloader.o)
      ___63-[MLKITx_GMVCloudVisionClient initWithCloudUri:apiKey:options:]_block_invoke in MLKitVision(GMVCloudVisionClient.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


2023-06-04 22:17:30.202 xcodebuild[58527:700921] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C98A10BC-CA1F-4950-876C-F0838CC39041, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C98A10BC-CA1F-4950-876C-F0838CC39041, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/dso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-arvxybtqruynjaclszenpgywswhk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal (in target ‘MyApp’ from project ‘MyApp’)
(1 failure)
```

Most of warning are also connected to:

```
Debug-iphonesimulator/React-logger/libReact-logger.a, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-arm64
```

This is my first time developing and starting iOS part of react-native and I have tried multiple solutions but none of those worked.

this is my rn info (react-native info)

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 80.06 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.14.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.22.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/dso/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.19 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: can you share your code in github

Comment: @LouaySleman Sorry mate I can't share repo beacuse it's private and not in my ownership, but I can provide some specific block of code, what do you need?

Comment: Try downgrading to Xcode 14.2

Comment: @Abe Hey mate just tried your solution, didn't help. Maybe lower version?